# What is the difference between objects and variables?

Tags: r

I want to know the difference between Variables and Objects in R. Is 'a'in the code provided an object or variable ? Where this a is going to be save, in heap or stack ?

```
a <- 1
```

Comment: An object of the type `data.frame` has n variables (i.e. columns)....Also `a` is a number. If `a <- c(1, 2, 3)` then `a` is a vector.

Comment: Everything in R is an object. There is no difference, from a data type perspective, between `1` and `c(1,2,3)`. The former is a vector of length 1. Also, you don't have control on whether R allocates memory on heap or stack.

Comment: Maybe I am thinking it more in terms of statistics. I think you should answer it @nicola

Comment: This is a relevant good read about objects in memory: [THE SECRET LIVES OF R OBJECTS](https://www.brodieg.com/2019/02/18/an-unofficial-reference-for-internal-inspect/)

Comment: @Sotos If a "dataset" is considered an object of data.frame type and columns in data.frame are called variables while every column holds more than one values. What we will call "a" in the line "a <= 1". In other languages we consider this as an variable which can store only one value. i.e. int a = 1;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference, from a data type perspective, between `1` and `c(1,2,3)`. Everything in R is an object. For instance:

```
a <- 1
b <- c(1,2,3)
typeof(a)==typeof(b)
#[1] TRUE
class(a)==class(b)
#[1] TRUE
```

R is a high level language and you don't have visibility on where and when R actually allocates memory.

Comment: I am pretty sure there was a way of tracing the object in memory, and change it within R (I might be wrong).

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, for instance there is `data.table::address` that tells you the address of an object. But, on the other hand, there is no way of telling R to allocate an object on the stack, for instance. You also have `copy`, which copies an object from a memory region to another. But the details of the memory allocation and garbage collection are hidden from the user.

Answer (score 1):

We can do object oriented programming in R. In fact, everything in R is an object.

An object is a data structure having some attributes and methods which act on its attributes.

Class is a blueprint for the object. We can think of class like a sketch (prototype) of a house. It contains all the details about the floors, doors, windows etc. Based on these descriptions we build the house.

House is the object. As, many houses can be made from a description, we can create many objects from a class. An object is also called an instance of a class and the process of creating this object is called instantiation.

While most programming languages have a single class system, R has three class systems. Namely, S3, S4 and more recently Reference class systems.

They have their own features and peculiarities and choosing one over the other is a matter of preference. Below, we give a brief introduction to them.

S3 class is somewhat primitive in nature. It lacks a formal definition and object of this class can be created simply by adding a class attribute to it.

> ## create a list with required components
>
> s <- list(name = "Rafay", age = 21, GPA = 3.72)
>
> ## name the class appropriately
>
> class(s) <- "student"

S4 class are an improvement over the S3 class. They have a formally defined structure which helps in making object of the same class look more or less similar.

< setClass("student", slots=list(name="character", age="numeric", GPA="numeric"))

Now if you're from a c#, c background you must think that
When in c#
int a =2 #it is called variable
Student std1=new Student() ;# it is called object
But as mentioned above everything in R is called object.